# Login with facebook on webview

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have webview in my app.My site has backlinks facebook page. 
When click the links, i wnat automatically login to the facebook.
pls help me
thanks all

Comment: please try to provide what you have achieved so far